# Create Dictionaries from part of the json File

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to create two seperate dictionaries, one that only holds the car information, and the second, which just holds the ticket information.

```
{
"cars": [{
        "model": "toyota",
        "plate": "A11",
        "tickets": [{
                "amount": 50,
                "type": "A1"
            },
            {
                "amount": 34,
                "type": "A2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "model": "mazda",
        "plate": "A11",
        "tickets": [{
                "amount": 50,
                "type": "A1"
            },
            {
                "amount": 34,
                "type": "A2"
            }
        ]
    }
 ]
}


import json

with open('jsonfile', 'r') as data:
cars_dict = json.load(data)
```

Then the loop to generate the two separate `dict`s. I created the loop, but still not achieving the result properly.

Desired output will be:

```
dict_cars = [{'Model':'Toyota', 'Plate':'A11'},
             {'Model':'Mazda', 'Plate':'A13'}]
```

or

```
dict_cars = [{'Model':'Toyota', 'Plate':'A11', Tickets[......]},
             {'Model':'Mazda', 'Plate':'A13'}, Tickets[......]]

dict_tickets = [{'amount:50',type:'A1'},
                {'amount:34',type:'A2'},
                {'amount:50',type:'A1'},
                {'amount:34',type:'A2'}]
```

Comment: please show the desired output

Comment: Please also update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Neither of those are dictionaries.

Comment: Please don't comment to provide updates. Use the edit 'button' and update the question directly.

Comment: I have added the output to the question. thank you

Comment: `('Model':'Toyota, 'Plate':'A11')` not valid syntax

Comment: what yuou have tried? as of now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply loop through the json object and parse the value:

```
d = {
"dict_cars": [{
        "model": "toyota",
        "plate": "A11",
        "tickets": [{
                "amount": 50,
                "type": "A1"
            },
            {
                "amount": 34,
                "type": "A2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "model": "mazda",
        "plate": "A11",
        "tickets": [{
                "amount": 50,
                "type": "A1"
            },
            {
                "amount": 34,
                "type": "A2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}

dict_cars=[]
dict_tickets=[]
for i,j in d.items():
    for k in j:
        dict_cars.append({k.get('model',''):k.get("plate","")})
        for t in k.get('tickets',""):
            dict_tickets.append(t)

print("dict_cars = ",dict_cars)
print("dict_tickets = ",dict_tickets)
```

## out

`dict_cars =  [{'toyota': 'A11'}, {'mazda': 'A11'}]
 dict_tickets =  [{'amount': 50, 'type': 'A1'}, {'amount': 34, 'type': 'A2'}, {'amount': 50, 'type': 'A1'}, {'amount': 34, 'type': 'A2'}]`

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

with open('file.json', 'r') as data:
    text = data.read()

cars = json.loads(text)['cars']
tickets = []

for arr in cars:
    for item in arr['tickets']:
        tickets.append(item)

    del arr['tickets']

print(tickets)
print(cars)
```

output:

```
[{u'amount': 50, u'type': u'A1'}, {u'amount': 34, u'type': u'A2'}, {u'amount': 50, u'type': u'A1'}, {u'amount': 34, u'type': u'A2'}]
[{u'plate': u'A11', u'model': u'toyota'}, {u'plate': u'A11', u'model': u'mazda'}]
```